# Having both set_under and set_bad working in matplotlib contourf plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a matplotlib contourf plot that has all values under a specified value in white (including zero) and that has all nan values (representing missing data) in black. I can't seem to get the nan values to be a different color then the under/zero values.A simplified example of the problem is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Generate some random data for a contour plot
Z = np.random.rand(10,10)
Z[0:3,0:3] = np.nan # some bad values for set_bad
Z[0:3,7:10] = 0 # some zero values for set_under
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Mask the bad data:
Z_masked = np.ma.array(Z,mask=np.isnan(Z))

# Get the colormap and set the under and bad colors
colMap = cm.gist_rainbow
colMap.set_bad(color='black')
colMap.set_under(color='white')

# Create the contour plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 9))
contourPlot = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z_masked,cmap = colMap,vmin = 0.2)
plt.colorbar(contourPlot)
plt.show()
```

Using this I get the figure linked below, where both the nan values (bottom left) and zero values (bottom right) are white - I'm not sure why the nan values are not black.

[image: buggy figure]

[Generated Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APuR6.png)

Comment: Not sure if this can help you, but please read the last lines of comment in this [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html)

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar Ah, you got it right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is the example pointed to by  @ViníciusAguia that notes that contourf simply does not *draw* anything where the data is invalid.  If you had flipped the black and white in your example it would have looked like it worked!

A way to get what you want is to set the facecolor on your axes to the color you want for 'bad':

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
plt.ion()

# Generate some random data for a contour plot
Z = np.random.rand(10,10)
Z[0:3,0:3] = np.nan # some bad values for set_bad
Z[0:3,7:10] = 0 # some zero values for set_under
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Mask the bad data:
Z_masked = np.ma.array(Z,mask=np.isnan(Z))

# Get the colormap and set the under and bad colors
colMap = cm.gist_rainbow
# this has no effect see last comment block in
# https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contourf_demo.html
# colMap.set_bad(color='black')
colMap.set_under(color='white')

# Create the contour plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
contourPlot = ax.contourf(X,Y,Z_masked,cmap = colMap,vmin = 0.2, extend='both')
fig.colorbar(contourPlot)
# This is effectively 'bad' for contourf
ax.set_facecolor('k')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks tacaswell and @ViníciusAguia , this works well!

Answer (score 3):

Since the masked regions are not filled at all, you might simply set the background of the plot to the color you would want to attribute to the "bad" values,  `plt.gca().set_facecolor("black")`.

Complete example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Generate some random data for a contour plot
Z = np.random.rand(10,10)
Z[0:3,0:3] = np.nan # some bad values for set_bad
Z[0:3,7:10] = 0 # some zero values for set_under
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.arange(10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

# Mask the bad data:
Z_masked = np.ma.array(Z,mask=np.isnan(Z))

# Get the colormap and set the under and bad colors
colMap = cm.gist_rainbow
colMap.set_under(color='white')

# Create the contour plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 9))
plt.gca().set_facecolor("black")
contourPlot = plt.contourf(X,Y,Z_masked,cmap = colMap,vmin = 0.2)
plt.colorbar(contourPlot)
plt.show()
```

[image]