# Python Matplotlib: how to add "bad" color to the legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, confusion-matrix

The color map in matplotlib allows to mark "bad" values, i.e. NaNs, with a specific color. When we plot the color bar afterwards, this color is not included. Is there a preferred approach to have both the contiuous color bar and a discrete legend for the specific color for bad values?

**Edit:**
Certainly, it's possible to make use of the ["extend" functionality](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#discrete-intervals-colorbar). However, this solution is not satisfactory. The function of the legend/colorbar is to clarify the meaning of colors to the user. In my opinion, this solution does not communicate that the value is a NaN.

Code example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data[0:3, 0:3] = np.nan  # some bad values for set_bad

colMap = cm.RdBu
colMap.set_bad(color='black')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 9))
confusion_matrix = plt.imshow(data, cmap=colMap, vmin=0, vmax=1)
plt.colorbar(confusion_matrix)
plt.show()
```

Which produces:

[image: Confusion Matrix]

Comment: You can do this using one of the approaches shown at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#discrete-intervals-colorbar    Set the color of the bad value e.g. to -999 and use the keyword `extend`.

Answer (score 1):

A legend element could be created and used as follows:

```py
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=colMap(np.nan), label='Bad values')]
plt.legend(handles=legend_elements)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using one of the approaches used for out-of-range plotting shown at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/colors/colorbar_only.html#discrete-intervals-colorbar

Set the color of the bad value e.g. to -999 and use the keyword `extend`.

Another approach is to used masked plotting as shown [here](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/masked_demo.html).

Another way could be to use [cmap.set_bad()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Colormap.html#matplotlib.colors.Colormap.set_bad). An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43943784/having-both-set-under-and-set-bad-working-in-matplotlib-contourf-plot).

Comment: You could use a custom tick label https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244514/modify-tick-label-text

Answer (score 0):

While adding it to the legend is an option (see [JohanC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61212828/21260084)), the color semantically belongs to the colorbar and I usually don't want a separate legend on a color-coded plot with a colorbar.

After experimenting for way too long, the best way I found is to add **a separate single-color colorbar** that associates with the proper colorbar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data[0:3, 0:3] = np.nan  # some bad values for set_bad

colMap = cm.RdBu
colMap.set_bad(color='purple')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 9))
plt.grid(False)
confusion_matrix = plt.imshow(data, cmap=colMap, vmin=0, vmax=1)
cbar= plt.colorbar(confusion_matrix)

sm = cm.ScalarMappable(cmap= mpl.colors.ListedColormap([colMap.get_bad()]))
divider = make_axes_locatable(cbar.ax)  # for tight_layout compatibility
nan_ax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size= "5%", pad= "3%", aspect= 1, anchor= cbar.ax.get_anchor())
nan_ax.grid(visible=False, which='both', axis='both')  # required for Colorbar constructor below
nan_cbar = mpl.colorbar.Colorbar(ax=nan_ax, mappable=sm, orientation='vertical')
nan_cbar.set_ticks([0.5], labels=['NaN'])
nan_cbar.ax.tick_params(length= 0)  # optional to drop the unnecessary tick line
```

Size and distance of the `NaN` colorbar can be adjusted via `size` and `pad` above.

[image: matplotlib rendering of the code above]

*Elaboration on proposed alternative*

As you wrote in your edit, another option is to abuse `extend`, but the color will be added directly below/above the colorbar with no visible gap and there is no clear way of associating a label with it in the API:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

data = np.random.rand(10, 10)
data[0:3, 0:3] = np.nan  # some bad values for set_bad

colMap = cm.RdBu
colMap.set_under(color='purple')

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 9))
plt.grid(False)
confusion_matrix = plt.imshow(data, cmap=colMap, vmin=0, vmax=1)
cbar= plt.colorbar(confusion_matrix, extend='min', extendrect=True)
```

[image: matplotlib rendering of the code above]

The third option would be to create a new colormap and reserve a fraction for the NaN value, but that is also cumbersome and allows for no clear gap to the real colors.